# MySQL: Proper way to implement a "conditional primary key"

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, database-design, flask-sqlalchemy

Here is my submissions table. Users make Submissions on Challenges. They can make as many submissions as they want, until there is a correct submission. Once a correct submission is recorded there should be no more submissions given a `challenge_id`, `user_id` combo. I was initially enforcing this constraint from within my app but would like to move this constraint to the DB.

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id      | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| challenge_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| correct      | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| timestamp    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| flag         | varchar(512) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

## What I've Tried

I've tried making the primary key of the table be `KEY(user_id, challenge_id, correct)`. The problem with this is that there could be multiple submissions as long as correct is false.

What is one way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to record the incorrect submissions, don't.

If you do need the full history, it cannot be done by a `UNIQUE` key, as you observed.

Plan A:  Add a `TRIGGER` that checks for inserting a second correct answer.  Meanwhile, something else would need to be the PK.

Plan B:  Have a table of correct submissions and a table of incorrect (or possibly all) submissions.  Neither would necessarily need the `correct` column.  And perhaps some other columns don't have to be in both tables.  The PKs would be different.